# GZIP file system code for Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, gzip

GZIP allows one to use file system codes. See page 7 of [RFC 1952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt).

What is (are?) the GZIP file system code(s) to use for Linux?